# Java Equals and Pass by value confusion

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

I have written following program to test the equals and Java pass by value functionality (as per documentation Java is pass by value), so when I pass object `a` to the method I am actually passing the heap values. What is if I change the reference of the object in the method? What will happen?

```
package equalstest;

public class EqualsMethodTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EqualsMethodTest a = new EqualsMethodTest();
        EqualsMethodTest b = new EqualsMethodTest();
        System.out.println(" Comparing a and B");
        System.out.println(a == b);
        System.out.println(a.equals(b));
        EqualsMethodTest c = compare(a, b);

        System.out.println(" Comparing B and C after interchanging references");

        System.out.println(b == c);
        System.out.println(b.equals(c));

        System.out.println(" Comparing A and C after interchanging references");

        System.out.println(a == c);
        System.out.println(a.equals(c));
    }

    static EqualsMethodTest compare(EqualsMethodTest a, EqualsMethodTest b) {
        EqualsMethodTest c = a;
        a = b;
        return c;
    }
}
```

I am getting below output:

> Comparing a and B
>   before alteration a == b false
>   before alteration a.equals b false
>   Comparing B and C after interchanging references
>   after  alteration b == c false
>   after alteration b.equals c false
>   Comparing A and C after interchanging references
>   after alteration a == c true
>   after alteration a.equals c true

- What actually happens in the method `compare`?
- When I create a new reference `c` does it point to memory location of `a`?
- What happens when I assigning `b` to `a`?

Comment: Yes, `c` actually has the same reference as `a` after the method compare is called. Also nothing happend when you assign `b` to `a`, since you did in a local scope `compare`, which wont affect the original references in your main method. in addition [the common SO question for this topic answers this well multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?rq=1)

Comment: You probably overlooked the fact that objects are not passed or assigned in Java but a reference (pointer) to them.

Comment: `compare` does _nothing_ except return its first argument.

Answer (score 2):

> When i create a new reference c does it point to memory location of a?

Yes because you didn't actually create `c`(with *new*), you just told to point c to a.

> What happends when i assigning b to a ?

Same thing here too, your `a` points to `b` from now on. Hence finally your c also point's `a` where you pointed `b` to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

A reference can point to new object or any existing object.

```
EqualsMethodTest a = new EqualsMethodTest();
   // Reference--^    ^--- new object
```

So when you do `EqualsMethodTest c = a;`, it means `c` will point to the object whom `a` is pointing. So basically at this point of time `c` and `a` both references are pointing to same object. Similarly it happens for `a = b;`.

---

> Pass by value confusion

Java **references** are passed by value.

Comment: @Tom sorry, did not get you.

Comment: @Tom, Ohh I see. I pointed out that for this question regarding passing variables to methods.

Comment: Well, then there is nothing to worry here :D.

Comment: @Vinayb did any of the answers cleared your confusion?

Answer (score 1):

Calling Java "pass-by-value" is, although technically correct, quite confusing. Java is pass-by-value, but the values which are passed are references. So what happens in your method is the following:

1. `EqualsMethodTest c = a;` The value of the the new variable `c` is made equal to the value of parameter `a`. Thus, `c` now is a reference to the same object as `a`.
2. `a = b;` The value of the variable `a` is made equal to the value of `b`. Thus `a` and `b` are now references to the same object.
3. `return c;` The value of `c`, which is a reference to the object that `a` originally pointed to, is returned.

Because Java is pass-by-value, nothing changes in the code which calls `compare`. So if you call

```
`compare(a,b);`
```

the variabes `a` and `b` still point to the same objects as before; the change made by the second line of the `compare` method is local to the method.

Comment: When i do a=b now a points to b and since c pointed to a should not c point to where a is now pointing which is nothing but b.

Comment: @Vinay b. No. The `EqualsMethodTest c = a` comes *before* the `a = b`. So `c` points to the object `a` originally pointed to. Only afterwards the value of `a` is changed. You have to distinguish between the reference and the object the reference refers to.

Comment: when a=b here reference of a is pointing to location of b  is it ?

Comment: It points to the same object that `b` points to, yes. But `a = b` only changes `a`, not `c`, so `c` still points to the object that `a` originally pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you declare EqualsMethodTest you are actually creating a pointer to one.
So in your compare() function you are creating a new pointer, c, which points to the same place as a. Then you are telling the pointer a to point to location b.

Before the change you had pointer a pointing to value a and pointer b pointing to value b. After the change you have the pointer c pointing to value a, the pointer a pointing to value b, and the pointer b pointing to value b.